# $AA^{T}B=AA^{T}C $ implies $A^{T}B=A^{T}C$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This question was asked in a masters exam for which I am preparing.

> Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ real matrix.
>
> (a) Show that $N(A) \cap \operatorname{Im}(A^{T})=\{0\}$, where $A^{T}$  is the transpose of $A$.
>
> (b) If for two suitable matrices $B$ and $C$ we have  $AA^{T}B=AA^{T}C $ then show that  $A^{T}B=A^{T}C$.

**Attempt:**

(a)  Let $v \in N(A) \cap  \operatorname{Im}(A^{T})$. As $v=A^{T}w$, for some $n\times1$ of order  $w$  and multiplying it by $A$ I get $0=Av=A(A^{T}w)$. But I don't know how to proceed now as rank of $A$ is not given.

(b) I did a bit of manipulation and got
$AA^{T}(B-C)=0$ (it's trivial to see) but I don't know how should I proceed next.

I have done a course on linear algebra and studied from Hoffman-Kunze.

Kindly provide some hints.

Comment: What exactly is $N(A)$? The kernel of $A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints.
(a) $AA^Tw=0$ implies $w^TAA^Tw=0$. Show that $A^Tw=0$.
(b) $A^T(B-C)$ is in $N(A)\cap\operatorname{Im}A^T$.